# Error : unable to find valid certification path to requested target (sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on a spring boot project and doing the local setup for my spring boot application. I am getting SunCertPathBuilderException.Have tried many poosible ways to solve it by taking help from stackoverflow, also install the certs as part of keystore, but not completed , still stuck I just want to run the spring boot application

## Configuration Argument

Before running the spring boot application i am configuring the application with below arguments for ssl.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

## Exception Stack Trace

```
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2022-03-30 10:54:53,252 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:54,275 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:55,395 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:56,622 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:57,972 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:59,458 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate:154] Fail fast is set and there was an error reading configuration from consul.
2022-03-30 10:54:59,465 ERROR [main] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure:826] Application run failed
com.ecwid.consul.transport.TransportException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:83) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.makeGetRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:36) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:139) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulRawClient.makeGetRequest(ConsulRawClient.java:128) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValue(KeyValueConsulClient.java:70) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.kv.KeyValueConsulClient.getKVValue(KeyValueConsulClient.java:59) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.ecwid.consul.v1.ConsulClient.getKVValue(ConsulClient.java:594) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locate(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(PropertySourceLocator.java:52) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator.locateCollection(ConsulPropertySourceLocator.java:79) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b35ebf8.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor$1.doWithRetry(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.RetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(RetryOperationsInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.retry.annotation.AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AnnotationAwareRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-retry-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.consul.config.ConsulPropertySourceLocator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f17a4faf.locateCollection(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-consul-config-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.qvc.finance.payment.profile.update.CustomerFinancialProfileProcessorApplication.main(CustomerFinancialProfileProcessorApplication.java:36) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:370) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:313) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:458) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:172) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1500) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1415) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:421) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:221) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:165) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.5.12.jar:4.5.12]
    at com.ecwid.consul.transport.AbstractHttpTransport.executeRequest(AbstractHttpTransport.java:70) ~[consul-api-1.4.5.jar:na]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638) ~[na:na]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have ssl enabled so you have to provide a certificate. You can install it in your jvm for example.

Comment: Is it enabled by default since a newer version? Because I'm running into this after upgrading to Spring 2.7.1 suddenly. Is there a chance to disable it?